# JavaFX: Undecorated Window

Tags: java, windows, javafx, toast, javafx-2

I am attempting to make a Windows PC Toast notification. Right now I am using a mixture of Swing and JavaFX because I did not find a way to make an undecorated window with FX. I would much prefer to only use JavaFX.

So, how can I make an undecorated window?

**Edit:** I have discovered that you can create a stage directly with `new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)`.

Now all I need to know is how to initialize the toolkit so I can call my `start(Stage stage)` method in `MyApplication`. (which `extends Application`)

I usually call `Application.launch(MyApplication.class, null)`, however that shields me from the creation of the `Stage` and initialization of the `Toolkit`.

So how can I do these things to allow me to use `start(new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED))` directly?

Comment: For security reasons, this is unlikely to be possible.

Comment: Security reasons? Swing has the capability. Why would JavaFX be any different?

Comment: Because it runs in a browser and might be used to fake system popups.  (I know very little about JavaFX)

Comment: Oh. My JavaFX application is a Desktop Application. It does not run on  a browser. But FX can run on a browser.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I don't get your motivation for preliminary calling the start()-method setting a stage as undecorated, but the following piece of code should do what you want to achieve.

```
package decorationtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DecorationTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it makes an undecorated frame but it also ads it to the task bar. I guess what I want is a parent-less popup?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work without mixing with Swing. A solution could be to make a Swing-based wrapper application for the tray icon.

Comment: @Dorothy This is really old, but for sake of future visitors, calling `initOwner()` on the `Stage` and passing a reference to your main stage will prevent the notification's stage from being added to the task bar.